# TeamCity + ASP.NET Webapp: Error about unclosed string literal?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, msbuild, teamcity

I have a solution where all projects are targeting .NET v4.5.1.

TeamCity (v9.0.4) previously has built the solution just fine.

Added an Asp.Net web application (MVC + WebAPI) to the solution, still targeted at .NET 4.5.1.

It [Works on My Machine<sup>tm</sup>](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program/), but TeamCity now fails the build with the following MSBuild error:

> [src\app\Web\Web.csproj] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(186, 67): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. There is an unclosed literal string. Line 186, position 67.

The offending line, when opening the .csproj file, corresponds to the first line of the following section:

```
<Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
    <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
  </Target>
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

### What I've Tried so Far:

- Commented the section I thought was offending. No change.
- Removed the section I thought was offending. No change.
- Realized the line numbers probably refer to the targets file.
- Tried completely removing / deleting and recreating the web application.
- Tried creating a new Web Project from within Visual Studio 2013 and committing that. Still failed.
- Submitted [a bug report on this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-41565) because it truly seems like it shouldn't be happening.

I can't think of any other leads or anything we're doing in a non-standard way.

Comment: Can you tell me if you're pulling in the MVC references via NuGet? If not then you'll need to install MVC on the build agents.

Comment: @DevOps that's a good lead; I'll check that out ASAP, Thanks!

Comment: @DevOps haven't been able to check it out yet; don't worry, it's for a client and won't be dropping off my radar. :) I'll check back as soon as I test it.

Comment: @DevOps so I think one or more of the packages in the default MVC web site is using Tasks.Dataflow from the GAC (though I'm having trouble confirming). Also, when MSBuild runs, it seems to have an appbase that is the MSBuild directory, not my app. going to post the log here and mess with it some more...

Answer (score 1):

The answer in this case -- though not an exact one -- was to install Build Tools 2015. Once this was installed, the version of MSBuild installed seemed to pick up on things fine.

Unfortunately, necessity forced us to fix the symptoms without really getting into the problem this time around.